# Query your MySQL server for table size by row count and physical size by database

Tags: sql, mysql, database

After writing a similar SQL procedure to check my table sizes several times, I wrote this stored procedure to check my MySQL database's table size. It will show you the table sizes and row count across all tables in a particular database. I use this to identify any scaling issues with my database and review storage.

**Stored procedure**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE checkTableSize 
(IN tableName VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT      
        table_name AS `Table`,      
        round(avg(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024)), 2) as `Size in MB`, 
        sum(table_rows) as rowCount  
    FROM information_schema.TABLES  where table_schema = tableName 
    GROUP by table_name
    ORDER by rowCount desc;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

**How to call results**

```
call checkTableSize('EnterDBNameHere');
```

I'd like to know if there are out-of-the-box solutions from MySQL, or more elegant solutions to my stored procedure. I also thought I'd share in case this helps anyone.

Comment: There's a single row per table, so why do you apply aggregate functions &  GROUP BY?